# How do I get the frame width of UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, width, uipickerview, uitoolbar, uialertcontroller

I'd like to get the width of UIAlertController frame so that I can specify the width of UIPickerView and UIToolbar which will come with the UIAlertController.

I've tried to use the following statement to get the width.

> alertPicker.view.frame.size.width

But, the width is as same as viewController's:

> self.view.frame.size.width

Any idea to get the width of the UIAlertController? Thanks a lot.

This is my code.

```
    UIAlertController *alertPicker = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:nil message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

    CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(8, 0, alertPicker.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2);
    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    UIToolbar* pickerToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(2, 0, alertPicker.view.frame.size.width, 44)];
    UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneBtnisClicked:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
    pickerToolbar.items = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flexSpace,doneBtn,nil];

   [alertPicker.view addSubview:pickerToolbar];
   [alertPicker.view addSubview:pickerView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the `UIAlertController` width.
[How to set height and width of a UIAlertController in IOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774038/how-to-set-height-and-width-of-a-uialertcontroller-in-ios-8/28425323)