# ios swift 3 - UIAlertController width

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Is there anyway to create a custom alertController that fit the width of the screen ?

I tried several things before asking this question
one of them is :

```
let width:NSLayoutConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: alertController.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: view.bounds.width )

alertController.view.addConstraint(width)
```

But this line of code always makes a horizontal space between my alertController and the Screen.

Comment: the UIAlertViewController is intended to be used as is via the documentation. You best alternative is to make a custom view yourself via a UIViewController, that way you can set the width as you please as well as other configurations.

Comment: the solution to change the width

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26774038/how-to-set-height-and-width-of-a-uialertcontroller-in-ios-8/58387922#58387922

the solution to change the height

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28425323/11054805

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I currently find in the Apple documents:

> Appearance of Alert Views:
>   You cannot customize the appearance of alert views.

This disappoints me as I think the message text in alert views is too small for many users.  DrPatience, in a comment above, suggests a possible workaround.
[Alert Views](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UIAlertView.html)

Comment: This is a deadlink

Comment: @WMios - Thanks. UIAlertView is now deprecated according to my search of the Apple docs.

Comment: Yeah it is now `UIAlertController` and there is not a way to adjust the size. The suggestion is to use a custom `UIView`.