# Get UIAlertController action sheet width

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uialertview, uialertcontroller

I have been banging my head a against the wall for a while now:

How can I get the width of a UIAlertController action sheet's view?

Saying `alert.view.frame.width` gives `view.frame.width`.

Also, I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37409826) question, but it simply does not work: it just changes the frame of the alert, and I don't see how I can get the width from it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would very much like an answer to this!

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40933616/ios-swift-3-uialertcontroller-width

Comment: @ronatory, I do not want to set the width, I just want to get it

Comment: "`alert.view.frame.width` gives `view.frame.width`" – I'm getting the correct result, what do you mean with this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The width of the `.actionSheet` type `UIAlertController` is the width of the `UIWindow` (in portrait mode) minus 10 points of padding on each side, irregardless of the device orientation.

E.g. in the case of an iPhone 7, which has a width of 375 points:

[image]

Unsurprisingly, 355 points is the same value I get from `alert.view.frame.width`, given that the value is accessed in the completion block of `present(_:​animated:​completion:​)`, i.e. after the view has appeared.

Comment: When I call `alert.view.frame.width` before presenting `alert`, the width I get is 375. Why is this?

Comment: Also, it is different for iPad, so I need a not-hardcoded way to get the width

Comment: Because the view controller containing the view hasn't been presented yet. Why it's 375 and not 0, I'm not certain, but I believe it falls under what you may call "undocumented behaviour".

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion What exactly do you need it for? Apparently it isn't enough for you to get the value from inside the completion block?

Comment: I wanted to present a custom view within the alert

Comment: @IHaveAQuestion Why not use constraints then?

Comment: Although I guess changing and maybe animating in the present completion block to the correct size is ok. Also I'm a little afraid of constraints.

Answer (score 0):

[xoudini's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42845472/5327882) is definitely a solution. But a disadvantage could be the little delay of adding the custom view with the right width in the completion block. See the gif:

[image]

So an alternative solution could be, just to use [this extension for UIDevice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26962452/5327882) and then by checking the `modelName`, you can set the width values of the the action sheet of the different devices (maybe a little bit hacky, but you would avoid the delay and can set the width before the completion block). Here are the different width sizes of the action sheets of the currently supported devices of iOS10:

- iPhone5/iPhone5s/iPhoneSE: 300
- iPhone6/iPhone6s/iPhone7: 355
- iPhone6Plus/iPhone6sPlus/iPhone7Plus: 394
- iPad 9.7/12.9/Retina/Air1/Air2: 300

Answer (score -1):

Though I am late here, but better late than never.

Width for alert view controller is set in constraints. To get the width of the alert controller, you can use:

```
for constraint in self.alertView.subviews[0].constraints {

  if constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.width {
  print("\(constraint.constant)")
  break
  }
}
```